# f2py speed with array ordering

Tags: python, performance, numpy, f2py

I'm writing some code in fortran (`f2py`) in order to gain some speed because of a large amount of calculations that would be quite bothering to do in pure Python.

I was wondering if setting NumPy arrays in Python as `order=Fortran` will kind of slow down
the main python code with respect to the classical C-style order.

Answer (score 3):

The order can make a big difference in the speed of a calculation.  The following shows a simple example:

```
In [15]: x = np.ones((1000, 1000))

In [16]: y = np.ones((1000, 1000), order='F')

In [17]: %timeit x.sum(axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.03 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit y.sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
```

In this example, summing the columns of a C-ordered array takes 8 times as long as summing them with a Fortran-ordered array. If the sum is performed over the other axis, the computation on the C ordered array is faster:

```
In [19]: %timeit x.sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit y.sum(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.09 ms per loop
```

So the answer to whether or not using Fortran ordered arrays will affect the performance of your Python code is "maybe".

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any slow-down. Since NumPy 1.6, most `ufuncs` (ie, the basic 'universal' functions) take an optional argument allowing a user to specify the memory layout of her array: by default, it's `K`, meaning that the 'the element ordering of the inputs (is matched) as closely as possible`.

So, everything should be taken care of below the hood.

At worst, you could always switch from one order to another with the `order` parameter of `np.array` (but that will copy your data and is probably not worth it).